# How to connect to Ubuntu Server 16.04 from Chrome Browser?

Tags: 16.04, server, connection, torrent-client

I keep getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I can't connect through the browser, only the command line. I want to use it as a torrenting server with a web-based GUI for the torrenting client, something like `torrentflux`, for example.

It's a 32-bit machine running Ubuntu Server 16.04 and I'm trying to connect with Chrome Browser on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.

Comment: If that was a web server then it would make sense to use a web browser. Otherwise I fail to see the point of it. Is it to check the torrents? If so, most bittorrent clients allow remote access (also via web)  but it is not enabled by default.

Comment: @MichaelBay I updated the question to explain.

Comment: The answer below work from inside your network. Accessing from outside requires port forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Ubuntu GNOME torrent client - Transmission - already provides the functionally you want but not enabled by default.

In order to enable it open Edit > Preferences > Remote

[image]

and select the options as pictured above. Authentication is optional.

After this you'll be able to connect to its web interface, from Google Chrome or any other web browser, by typing `IP_ADDRESS:9091` where IP_ADDRESS is the "torrenting servers"' IP address. If you changed the default port (9091) then also change the above accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the screenshot (MacOS) but it's the same.

Comment: I don't have a GUI. Do you know the commands?

Comment: You need to set it up by editing `/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json`